# htaccess rewrite folder to root

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, directory

I want to redirect (joomla - new setup, old setup has a dual language, this one only with one, and `/index.php/en/[content]` links not work, aliases is still same) `/index.php/en/[content]` to `/index.php/[content]`

With .htaccess rewrite, I tried few options without success.

Comment: What options did you try?

Answer (score 0):

this .htacess config redirect /index.php/en/(anypage) to /index.php/(anypage)

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule index.php/en/(.*) index.php/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^index.php/en/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

With this modification, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Froggiz answer(don't worked for me):
I modified the code, and it works correctly!

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php/en/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```